# How to set Maximum invalid login attempts diffrent then 0,3,5 or 10

Tags: permissions

Can you help / give ma a hint where can I change this property in Salesforce to 6 invalid login attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this value is hardcoded and cannot be changed. There is no information on changing this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/admin_password.htm) too.

Please consider submitting an Idea on Salesforce [Ideas exchange](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) stating the usecase so that Salesforce product development team can consider implementing in coming releases.

Similar Idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSx0QAG